# Is there a way to define public projection for the item in EVE?

Tags: eve

Is there any possibility to define a projection for unauthorized requests? For example I want to show some item fields for public get and show all item fields for authorized get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the request is unauthorized then it is going to get a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response with an empty payload (`Please provide proper credentials` aside), so I don't see the point of setting up different projections.

If you intend to use [Role Based Access Control](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#role-based-access-control) and are looking at ways of setting up different projections for each role, that's not currently supported I'm afraid, although you could use [different endpoints all consuming the same resource](http://python-eve.org/config.html#multiple-api-endpoints-one-datasource), each one with a different projection/schema and dedicated access role.

Comment: Different endpoints consuming the same resource looks good to me! Thanks Nicola